# Monday Silver Anniversary in Texas, need ideas

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels, restaurants

So I'm having a hard time where to go for our Silver Wedding Anniversary in or around Texas.

I had thought the Hyatt on the Riverwalk in San Antonio might be nice, but I heard restaurants are closed on Sunday and Monday there...

For family reasons we can't travel to far outside DFW and because of this huge diamond I bought her, the budget is now thin... :-)

Any ideas are welcome... But would like to get outside the metroplex...

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review the [Help Page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) to assist in asking a good question and then clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes please, be mor precise ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since it's the middle of the summer I would think you would like to avoid the coastal cities because of the humidity. In which case I would recommend Austin. You will not be limited in restaurant selection and since it's the capital, you can find a lot of monuments to tour. On your way there you might want to stop by one of the numerous BBQ places just outside of Austin.

That is about the best answer I can give you with the amount of detail you've given me.